# How do you place the right column above the left column in bootstrap when shrinking the page instead of the other way around?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
  />
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fuild padding">
    <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h2>Our padding</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin
                g elit. Nostrum, officiis.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png

            C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Thats all the code I use

When you shrink the site how do you make the picture go above and the text under in bootstrap instead of the over way around as in the picture

My assignment is that when the code is normal the picture should stay as normal on the right and the lorem on the left and when it shrinks the picture should go above and text down

Comment: Use flexbox and set a `flex-direction: reverse;`. Have you tried this

Comment: I want to do it in while using Bootstrap

Comment: [Flex - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) Bootstrap has flex capabilities

Comment: HI thanks so far! Im still having little trouble doing that.I put flex-sm-column-reverse on row padding and it moves that way when its large.I want it that way when it shriks to sm and when larger to be the way it was

Comment: Can you please add your CSS & HTML or create a fiddle?

Comment: Hi, its changed. You can see all my code

Comment: I misspoke in my first comment, try flex-wrap-reverse. Example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_flex-wrap&stacked=h)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help man